# SQL - how to select information from other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to sql and trying to build some kind of quiz. I made two tables and the schema is presented  on the picture.
[image: SQL select problem]

Probably I'm doing it wrong but have no idea how to make it right.
I want to display a question, all three possible answers and the good answer so I get the answers as a text not numbers.
I tried

```
select q.questiontext, q.answer1_id, q.answer2_id, q.answer3_id, a.answertext  
from questions q
join answers a on q.goodanswer = a.id
```

but I get Answers IDs where I want the text associated to the ID

Can you direct me what Im doing wrong?

Comment: add sample data and expected output

Comment: So your questions can have more than one answers and one good answer?

Comment: Yes, there should be 3 questions to choose from and only one is the right one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to join with the `answers` table separately for each column you want to display:

```
SELECT q.questiontext, a1.answertext AS answer1, a2.answertext AS answer2, a3.answertext as answer3, a4.answertext as good_answer
FROM questions AS q
JOIN answers AS a1 ON a1.id = q.answer1_id
JOIN answers AS a2 ON a2.id = q.answer2_id
JOIN answers AS a3 ON a3.id = q.answer3_id
JOIN answers AS a4 ON a4.id = q.goodanswer
```

Comment: It works. I tried it before but my syntax was bad. You made it clear. Is the way I designed the database a good way or would you make it in different way? Thank you

Comment: @PhiCato Instead of having separate columns for each answer ID, I would put a foreign key in the answers table that refers to the question ID. And the answers table could have a `correct` column that indicates whether it's the correcet answer. This is the solution suggested in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make questions and answers table.

Questions table:id, text

Answers table: id, question_id, status, text

```
SELECT a.* FROM questions as q, answers as a
WHERE a.question_id=q.id
```

Comment: You need to add something to indicate which answer is correct.